# Multiple Match Results From Array Search

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet

For the sake of MWE, I have an array in $AP$4:$BO$20 with a single string in each cell. The data in each cell is an alphanumeric code, such as 1,1a,2b,3c, etc.

Row 22, starting in column AQ, contains a single string that matches one or more of the strings in the array named above. Goal: using each string in AQ22:AO22, create a formula that extracts EVERY row number of the cells in the array $AP$4:$BO$20 that contain exactly the value in AQ22:AO22.

Bonus for doing it without using an array formula. VBA is not an option since this is Google Sheets, and I'd really prefer to avoid g-apps-script.

I've attempted using

```
  =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MIN(IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND(AQ22,$AP$4:$BO$20,1))),ROW($AP$4:$BO$20),"")),1))
```

and

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($AP$4:$BO$20,SMALL(IF($AP$4:$BO$20=AQ22,ROW($AP$4:$BO$20)-4),ROW(A1)),2),"")
```

and even the illustrious

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($AP$4:$BO$20,SMALL(IF($AP$4:$BO$20=AQ22,ROW($AP$4:$BO$20)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX($AP$4:$BO$20,SMALL(IF($AP$4:$BO$20=AQ22,ROW($AP$4:$BO$20)),ROW(1:1)),2))
```

Here is a [toy sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jo030C08oqB--SpYFfBnb0k-hnG0SbFv_swfPkzw70U/edit?usp=sharing) to test out ideas with using this information. Note the comment on the cell where the formula will begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the desired result correctly, but

```
= IfError( Filter( Row($AL$4:$AL$16), RegExMatch( $AL$4:$AL$16, "\b" & AQ22 & "\b" ) ), "")
```

results in `7`, and `9` in a separate cell below it. `\b` is a [word boundary](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#wordboundary) that matches between alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric character. If you want the result in one cell, you can join them:

```
=IfError(Join(",", Filter(Row($AL$4:$AL$16), RegExMatch($AL$4:$AL$16, "\b"&AQ22&"\b"))), "")
```

You can also match multiple values:

```
=IfError(Filter(Row($AL$4:$AL$16), RegExMatch($AL$4:$AL$16, "\b(" & Join("|", AQ22:AZ22) & ")\b")), "")
```

Comment: These work beautifully, and bonus for code to output the result as as a list. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel you can do it without a `CSE` entered formula, but I don't know if the `AGGREGATE` function is available in Sheets:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,1/((AQ$22=arr)*(LEN(arr)>0))*ROW(arr),ROWS($1:1)),"")
```

For an array entered formula:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF((AQ$22=arr)*(LEN(arr)>0),ROW(arr),""),ROWS($1:1)),"")
```

For either one of those formulas, enter in AQ24, then fill down until you get blanks, and across.  When you fill down, none of the "target rows" can be hidden (or else the result of the formula will be hidden).

> `arr` refers to `$AP$4:$BO$20`

Comment: `=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,1/((AQ$22=$AP$4:$BO$20)*(LEN(arr)>0))*ROW($AP$4:$BO$20),ROWS($1:1)),"")` results in blanks, and `=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SMALL(IF((AQ$22=$AP$4:$BO$20)*(LEN(arr)>0),ROW($AP$4:$BO$20),""),ROWS($1:1)),""))` gives blanks, interestingly, since it looks like it should work. Did you try it on the toy data sheet?

Comment: @Zediiiii Yes it worked on the data sheet when downloaded into Excel.  It only returned blanks if there was nothing to return.  Let me see if I can try it in sheets.

Comment: Ah, that's the issue, it does work in excel, but for some reason, not in sheets. Thanks for the great input. I've seen some weird data-type conversion problems in sheets that don't exist in excel, wonder if that's why?

Comment: @Zediiiii OK, as expected, the `AGGREGATE` function does not exist in Sheets, so that won't work.  The other formula works properly, however.  Your problem is that you did not replace `arr` within the `LEN` function.  Should read: `=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SMALL(IF((AQ$22=$AP$4:$BO$20)*(LEN($AP$4:$BO$20)>0),ROW($AP$4:$BO$20),""),ROWS($1:1)),""))`

Comment: Quite so, this works beautifully. Thanks. I'm sure the filter/regex combo is slightly more efficient than the array formula, but this works well nonetheless, and doesn't require regex - a bonus for non-coders such as myself.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is a very specific application in response to this question, for the sake of the knowledge base, I'd like to show how I dealt with an instance of multiple match values. There is likely a much better way, but here is one way.

To give this context, imagine the `LIST_CELL` is a list of question numbers 
(which are entered in as a header row, call the range `QUESTIONS`) on a test that correspond to certain standards, and the goal is to average only the questions that correspond to the standard next to which the list is written, and for each student. Using

```
=iferror(join(",",ArrayFormula(match(split(LIST_CELL,","),QUESTIONS,FALSE))),"")
```

The split function splits the a hand-entered list of questions on commas, the match function returns the column number of that particular question in `QUESTIONS`, and the join function joins the data back together. `ArrayFormula` allows the match to be performed on an array instead of just the first value.

Another single row heading lists the standards to which each question has been matched (possibly to more than one standard) by the comma separated list in `LIST_CELL`. For a column list of students in A:A, each standard needs to average the scores of every question that is listed next to the standard. This is accomplished by the nifty (if clunky):

```
average(ArrayFormula(hlookup(split(vlookup(LOOKUP_VAL,SEARCH_RANGE,COL_W_LIST),","),DATA_SOURCE,row(CURRENT_CELL))))
```

Breakdown from center outward:

`LOOKUP_VAL` is the value being looked up (the one that has multiple matches); in the example context, it's the standard.

`SEARCH_RANGE` is a range of cells containing both the list of lookup value (the standards in context) and the comma separated lists of column numbers generated by the first function. `COL_W_LIST` is the column number in the array `SEARCH_RANGE` that contains the list of row numbers matched from `LIST_CELL`.

`Split` takes the elements apart and placed them in a temporary array so that `hlookup` can be performed on each element. Via `ArrayFormula` the `hlookup` grabs each value on the same row in the appropriate `QUESTIONS` column - in context, it grabs the point scores for each question matched to the standard.

Finally, average is self-explanatory, and does take an array as input apparently.

These two functions in combination allow of use of indirect cell references in an array formula, and solves the much asked, "how do I include multiple matches in a calculation" question. At least in this specific context.