# Match() and Other lookup() Data Type Issue

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Toy example on [this sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16ItdCf1QR2UT-ePiOsK8ztfxiqwunS3EusqflZFWw5g/edit?usp=sharing)

After splitting a comma separated list containing alphanumeric characters (Column w:w in the example sheet), I am attempting to match each cell to an array ($A$1:$V$1 in the example sheet). Some work correctly, and some don't return any results, even though the characters match. If I copy and paste the correct value (say copy T1 to F10 in the example) the function operates correctly - so there's a data type issue.

I attempted some of the solutions [here](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/746309.html), and randomly typing the data in quotes (ie ="11bc") seems to work sometimes, but not always. I can't properly categorize the exact root of the issue any more than "obnoxious data type issue."

Comment: Look at the error message on the N/A cells - there is a leading space on cell `F10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to chris neilsen, I found that leading spaces via the trim function cause issues with match, so a simple

```
=substitute(REF," ","")
```

fixes the issue. If, by chance, anyone needs the lovely array match function that makes this question relevant, made for solving the question "how do I deal with multiple match outcomes," I'll post it here with citation to Slai who gave me the basic idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42543782/multiple-match-results-from-array-search).

```
=iferror(join(",",ArrayFormula(match(split(CELLTOSPLIT,","),ARRAYTOMATCHON,FALSE))),"")
```

look at the [toy data sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16ItdCf1QR2UT-ePiOsK8ztfxiqwunS3EusqflZFWw5g/edit?usp=sharing) in column y to see how it works.